# Por que tá dando erro nesse PHP para gravar um XML?

Tags: php, xml

To tentando fazer um XML simples que pega os dados cadastrados em uma página em PHP mas está dando erro, alguém pode me dizer o que é e como pode dar certo?

Erro que aparece ao apertar o botão:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Hierarchy Request Error' in C:\xampp...\cadastro.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp...\cadastro.php(17): DOMNode->appendChild(Object(DOMElement)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp...\cadastro.php on line 17

Código inteiro da página:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['insert'])){

$xml= new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->load('studentdb.xml');

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];

$rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("roo")->item(0);

$infoTag = $xml->createElement("info");
    $nomeTag = $xml->createElement("nome", $nome);
    $enderecoTag = $xml->createElement("endereco", $endereco);

    $nomeTag->appendChild($nomeTag);
    $enderecoTag->appendChild($enderecoTag);

$rootTag->appendChild($infoTag);
$xml->save('studentdb.xml');

}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="cadastro.php">
Informacoes <br>
Nome <input type="text" name="nome"> <br>
Endereco <input type="text" name="endereco"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Resposta épica relacionada (no SOen): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16344986/4734177

Comment: Adiciona o arquivo em questão.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php#67952

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro é porque você está tentando mover um node dentro dele mesmo.

[Aqui tem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16344986/3517631) uma explicação de uma pergunta igual a sua.

Espero ter ajudado.

ATUALIZANDO:

Da uma olhada na linha 17 e 18 do seu código. Acredito que seja o problema.

```js
$nomeTag->appendChild($nomeTag);
$enderecoTag->appendChild($enderecoTag);
```

Comment: Cacetada, me assustei com a foto do post kkkkkkk.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkk tb achei muito loco, mas não tem como não entender olhando para ela kkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: até entendi o que está acontecendo, só não entendi muito bem como arrumar :/

Comment: Editei a resposta, acredito que seja problema na linha 17 e18